How do I update an expired/revoked Personal Access Token (PAT) in git cli
I use GitLab as a version control system. I initially configured the Personal Access Tokens (PATs) and they come with an expiry. And when the tokens expire, you need to renew them.
I have repos which were already cloned and so had an existing git remote
configured with earlier token. In order to renew it, I need a way to do it via cli.
How can I update my Personal Access Token using Git CLI.

You can update the PAT by updating the remote using the following steps:
git remote -v 
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://[personal_access_token]@gitlab.com/path/to/repo.git


